# Impossible to create new Joomla User with User Class : Please enter your name

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, joomla-api

Dont' know why but since Joomla 3.9.22 (or 3.9 ?), when I create a User with User Class, I have the error "Please enter your name". **But the name field is not empty.**

Here is my simple code :

```
$udata = array(
            "name"=>$data['name'],
            "username"=>$data['user'],
            "password"=>$data['pass'],
            "email"=>$data['email'],
            "block"=>0,
            "groups"=>array("1","2"),
            "params"=>array(
                "admin_style" => "",
                "admin_language" => "",
                "language" => 'fr-FR',
                "editor" => "",
                "helpsite" => "",
                "timezone" => ""

            ),
            "requireReset"=>1
        );



        $user = new User;
        $user->save();

        if(!$user->bind($udata)) {


            return false;


        }
```

Here is the User Object:

```
object(Joomla\CMS\User\User)[440]
  protected 'isRoot' => null
  public 'id' => int 0
  public 'name' => string 'Test TEST' (length=9)
  
  ...    

  protected '_errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Veuillez saisir votre nom.' (length=26)
```

Someone could help me? Because I don't understand.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that You are actually just using a wrong sequence when you try to save a new user to the database.

In the correct sequence you first `bind()` the `$data` (user data array) to the `new User` object and then you can `save()` it. So your new user is not stored in the database by your code above.

The correct sequence:

```
$user = new User;
$user->bind($udata);
$user->save();
```

In an older post here you can see how you should apply exceptions (if you would like to):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904809/how-can-i-create-a-new-joomla-user-account-from-within-a-script